# How can I edit my post?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to edit my answer in this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195362/how-to-use-traditional-national-native-dates-and-calendars?rq=1) and add newer solution and more details to it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The full post (question and answers) has been **locked**. A post which is "locked" cannot be modified in any way.

The reason for which is was closed is exposed in the post :

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
>   not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do
>   not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This
>   question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

So I doubt it will be reopened. More info in the help topic [Locked posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts)